# how to take input of characters separated by space in java in hackerrank using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

hi i  want to know how to take input of characters separated Space" " in java using scanner for example first line contains (int)T (no of test cases) second line contains {int(N)}size  of an character array separated space then contains {int (X)} for some operation then in next line it contains (char ch(N) with input 1 and 0 and each character is separated by space

sample:

[image: pic 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanner.nextInt()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), it will take care of new line and space character. Please find below code snippet.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int x = sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();
for (int i=0;i<x;i++) {
    int temp = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```